# How to write value into text node in DOM?

Tags: dom

```
<div><p></p></div>
```

I found when put

in ,

```
$('div')[0].childNodes
```

it split the text node of  into 2 text nodes,

```
#=>[textnode,<p></p>,textnode]
```

if I want write the text 'this is text node 3' into the last child node,

something like:
    ('div')[0].childNodes[2].value = 'this is text node 3'

but value property doesn't work here.how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .value try this the following, and give us feedback if it works.

```
$('div')[0].childNodes[2].innerHTML = 'this is text node 3';
```

Comment: your code gives no error, and console return the value 'this is text node3' but it the related html code, there's nothing add to the text node

Comment: I have probably got the question wrong. Reformulating the question in simple and proper English would help. If you wanted to manipulate specify index in an array of elements, I have showed a quick and basic example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dZCyd/

It uses CSS nth-child selector. I hope that helps. :)